# Windows 8.1 SearchBox

Tags: windows-8.1

In my app I use `SearchPane` and I also want to use `SearchBox`. But on `Initialize()` I get an error `Cannot create instance of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Search Box'`. When I remove  `SearchPane`, it worked. 
Should I delete `SearchPane` from all my application, if I want to use `SearchBox`? Or I can use both?
[SearchBox MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252771)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Put more information about your situation here. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN indicates that SearchBox will fail to initialize if your app has registered a SearchPane.  For Windows 8.1, you should use a SearchBox.